# Including a dependency to JAX-RS API on classpath when compiling - Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

I am following Neo4j doc here: http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/server-unmanaged-extensions.html to Unmanaged Extensions. I am not able to compile HelloWorld example given there. I am facing problem in creating jar file. 
In the doc, There is a tip for compiling: "You will need to include a dependency to JAX-RS API on your classpath when you compile", I am not sure how to include this dependency with `jar` command. I am not using Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to download the jax-rs jars (and dependencies) from java.net:
https://jersey.java.net/download.html

I strongly recommend to use a build tool like maven, gradle or ivy to manage your dependencies though. Then you just have to add the java.net maven repository as source and it will be pulled automatically.

Comment: I started using Gradle, made things lot easier!